# Ограниченный доступ на сайт

Tags: php

```
<?
$admin = '111.222.333.44';
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']!=$admin)
{echo 'Доступ запрещен';exit;};
// и завершается выполнение скрипта
?>
```

Вот дан скрипт. Он будет пускать на страницу только тех, у кого IP-Адрес 111.222.333.44.
Вопрос, как пускать на страницу `site.com/test.php` только тех, кто перешел отсюда `site.com/index.php` - знаю, что это через REFERER. Это вообще возможно или нет?

Comment: В этой стране когда-нибудь будут на сайты ставить нормальную защиту вообще или нет?))

Автору - защита по полю РЕФЕРЕР - не защита. Я пару лет назад яндекс нагибал через такую дыру.

Comment: Мне именно доступ по реферер нужен, это возможно?

Comment: Возможно конечно, только мне нужно сек 15, чтобы сломать его. Вы правда хотите заморочиться?

Comment: я знаю, что реферер можно легко подменить.. но все же... скиньте пожалуйста код

Comment: Все так негодуют, типа можно подменить реферер и т.д. Но блин, это тоже самое что сказать что можно легко подменить пароль, откуда кто знает что будет проверятся "http://site.com/index.php", а не "http://MYsite.com/index.php". Это и есть как пароль.

Comment: Ну если я перешел с индекса на тест, а потом обновил и меня послали - я заподозрю, что что-то тут не так) Вообще имелись в виду, конечно, серьезные сайты, где такая защита не "по приколу" стоит, а с серьезной на нее надеждой.

Comment: да не.. мне это не для защиты нужно.. спасибо))

Comment: Не, не комильфо ваш вариант. Делай через авторизацию. Рефер можно подделать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<? if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) || ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != 'http://site.com/index.php')) die('Access denied.'); ?>
```

Comment: По логике ответ надо плюснуть, но душа не согласна. =)  
@JavaBitz, слева от ответа есть галочка. Нажмите ее, чтобы принять ответ. Заодно и вам +2 к репутации.